# App targeting Fall Creators Update: Installation/run on Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

My UWP app uses NavigationView XAML control. It was introduced IMHO in Fall Creators Update. My phone is 1709, build: 10.0.15254.369. So, this app should be installable and runnable on this phone. I set minimal targeting version in Visual Studio to 10.0.16299 (this is the only available version for Fall Creators Update there). But bundled application seems to be not installable (after installation I don't see it in list of installed apps in the phone). When I decrease minimal targeting version - it's installing on the phone but fails on run (I suppose due to used NavigationView control). So, question is: why app is not installing on this phone and how to create "humburder-like menu" in this situation (I have NavigationView control only in my Visual studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app has minversion=16299 it means it can only be installed on operating systems with version 16299 and above. Your device is on OS version 15254, so it can't run apps that target 16299.

Another way to put it: All APIs that have been introduced in SDK 16299 are not supported/available on the latest build for Windows Phone.

Comment: hm, OK. Am I right, that Visual Studio controls palette does not help to filter controls by version? How can I select controls for my phone's OS version only?

Comment: Is it possible to link with controls library statically? In this case my app on mobile phone will not depends on installed dotnet (it will be bundled with the app). Is this possible?

Comment: No, not possible today.